# Create a VB script to send the keys to open up a program with specific settings

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a VB script to send the keys to open up a program/application with specific settings. So, after the application has been started, choosing those very specific settings would involve pressing 2 buttons inside the application UI (1st button to choose specific set of options, and 2nd button to save those options).

I will then create a batch file to call the mentioned VB script on boot.

So far, I got this:

`Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^%1"`

I've searched and searched, but couldn't figure out how to be able choose/save options once the app has been started, if it's even possible?

Thank you in advance for helping out!

Disclaimer: I am not a technical person, so forgive me if noob question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script to start an application (notepad), then send some keystrokes to it:

```
'VBScript Example
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "c:\windows\notepad.exe"

' add delay here

WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"

WshShell.SendKeys "Hello World!"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "abc"
WshShell.SendKeys "{CAPSLOCK}"
WshShell.SendKeys "def"
```

Perhaps this can be adapted to your needs?

The `WshShell.AppActivate` command is used to bring the program (with the specified window title) to the foreground.

You might want to add a delay to allow the program time to start before sending the keystrokes. This can be done by adding a sleep() call just after Wshell.Run:

```
' Sleep for 5 seconds (5000 msec)
WScript.Sleep(5000)
```

Also, here's a [list of key-codes](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/add_info/keys_mnemonics.htm) that you can use.